# IF NULL function in mysql doesn't work

Tags: mysql, if-statement, null, zero

im making this query but it returns empty and i need to return 0, i've been reading about it and it seems that with IFNULL function this can be solve but mysqlWorkbench marks a syntax error.

hope anyone can help me. Thanks

```
SELECT  IF NULL( "00:00:00", "03:00:00", count(*)
FROM    
        compose.TBL_USERS_TAGS ut  join 
        compose.TBL_USERS u on ut.ID_USER = u.ID_USER  join 
        compose.TBL_TAGS t on ut.ID_TAG = t.ID_TAG  join 
        compose.TBL_IN_OUT i on i.TAG_ADDRESS = t.TAG_ADDRESS  join
        compose.TBL_EVENTS e on e.TAG_ADDRESS  = i.TAG_ADDRESS  

WHERE  (((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, e.CREATION_DATE,i.IN_DATE)) <='00:02:00' AND 
       (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, e.CREATION_DATE, i.IN_DATE)) >=  '00:00:00' ))OR
       (e.CREATION_DATE > i.IN_DATE AND e.CREATION_DATE < i.OUT_DATE) AND 
       (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, i.in_date,i.out_date)) >= '00:00:20' AND 
       (convert(i.IN_DATE, TIME) >= "00:00:00" AND convert(i.OUT_DATE, TIME)  <= "03:00:00")

GROUP BY "00:00:00", "03:00:00",0);
```

Comment: for thi kind of test you should use IF Exists

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this :

SELECT IFNULL(field_name, "value");

Comment: Your answer looks like a comment, you should write in that section :)